# Customizing search box in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a search box that searches states and my selections are able to transferred to another bucket. My goal is for the user to be able to press enter upon searching the state they are interested in and push their result to the selection bucket. For example, user puts New Hampshire in search box and presses enter -- New Hampshire disappears from the list of selections and is transferred to the selection bucket. Currently the user would have to double click on New Hampshire after searching to push the selection to the other box. Furthermore, New Hampshire doesn't disappear from the list of selections if it is pushed to the selected bucket.

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$main <- renderUI({
source("chooser.R")
chooserInput("mychooser","Available frobs","Selected frobs",
row.names(USArrests),c(),size=20,multiple=TRUE)})
})
```

**ui.R**

```
source("chooser.R")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
uiOutput("main")
))
```

**chooser.R**

```
chooserInput <- function(inputId, leftLabel, rightLabel, leftChoices, rightChoices,
                         size = 5, multiple = FALSE) {

  leftChoices <- lapply(leftChoices, tags$option)
  rightChoices <- lapply(rightChoices, tags$option)

  if (multiple)
    multiple <- "multiple"
  else
    multiple <- NULL

  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(
      tags$script(src="chooser-binding.js"),
      tags$style(type="text/css",
                 HTML(".chooser-container { display: inline-block; }")
      )
    )),
    div(id=inputId, class="chooser",style="",
        div(
          div(style="min-width:100px;",
              tags$input(type="text",class="chooser-input-search",style="width:100px;")
          )
        ),
        div(style="display:table",
            div(style="min-width:100px; display:table-cell;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-left-container",
                    style="width:100%;",
                    tags$select(class="left", size=size, multiple=multiple, leftChoices,style="width:100%;min-width:100px")
                )
            ),
            div(style="min-width:50px; display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-center-container",
                    style="padding:10px;",
                    icon("arrow-circle-o-right", "right-arrow fa-3x"),
                    tags$br(),
                    icon("arrow-circle-o-left", "left-arrow fa-3x")
                )
            ),
            div(style="min-width:100px; display:table-cell;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-right-container", style="width:100%;",
                    tags$select(class="right", size=size, multiple=multiple, rightChoices,style="width:100%;")
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
}

registerInputHandler("shinyjsexamples.chooser", function(data, ...) {
  if (is.null(data))
    NULL
  else
    list(left=as.character(data$left), right=as.character(data$right))
}, force = TRUE)
```

**chooser-bindings.js (in www folder)**

```
(function() {

var options = [];
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);
    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      options = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
             $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
      if (selectSingleMatch === true && 
          $(select).children().length === 1) {
        $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
      }
    });
  });
};

function updateChooser(chooser) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var left = chooser.find("select.left");
    var right = chooser.find("select.right");
    var leftArrow = chooser.find(".left-arrow");
    var rightArrow = chooser.find(".right-arrow");

    var canMoveTo = (left.val() || []).length > 0;
    var canMoveFrom = (right.val() || []).length > 0;

    leftArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveFrom);
    rightArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveTo);
}

function move(chooser, source, dest) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var selected = chooser.find(source).children("option:selected");
    var dest = chooser.find(dest);
    dest.children("option:selected").each(function(i, e) {e.selected = false;});
    dest.append(selected);
    updateChooser(chooser);
    chooser.trigger("change");
}

$(".chooser").change(function(){

});

$(document).on("change", ".chooser select", function() {
    updateChooser($(this).parents(".chooser"));
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .right-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .left-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.left", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.right", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

var binding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

binding.find = function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".chooser");
};

binding.initialize = function(el) {
    updateChooser(el);
    $(function() {
      $('.left').filterByText($('.chooser-input-search'), true);
    }); 
};

binding.getValue = function(el) {
return {
    left: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.left option").map(function(i, e) { return      e.value; })),
    right: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.right option").map(function(i, e) {   return e.value; }))
}
};

binding.setValue = function(el, value) {
// TODO: implement
};

binding.subscribe = function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.chooserBinding", function(e) {
        callback();
    });
};

binding.unsubscribe = function(el) {
    $(el).off(".chooserBinding");
};

binding.getType = function() {
return "shinyjsexamples.chooser";
};

Shiny.inputBindings.register(binding, "shinyjsexamples.chooser");

})();
```

As you can see this is pretty much a shameful copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works somewhat

chooser.R

```
chooserInput <- function(inputId, leftLabel, rightLabel, leftChoices, rightChoices,
                         size = 5, multiple = FALSE) {

  leftChoices <- lapply(leftChoices, tags$option)
  rightChoices <- lapply(rightChoices, tags$option)

  if (multiple)
    multiple <- "multiple"
  else
    multiple <- NULL

  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(
      tags$script(src="chooser-binding.js"),
      tags$style(type="text/css",
                 HTML(".chooser-container { display: inline-block; }")
      )
    )),
    div(id=inputId, class="chooser",style="",
        div(
          div(style="min-width:100px;",
              tags$input(type="text",class="chooser-input-search",style="width:100px;")
          )
        ),
        div(style="display:table",
            div(style="min-width:100px; display:table-cell;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-left-container",
                    style="width:100%;",
                    tags$select(class="left", size=size, multiple=multiple, leftChoices,style="width:100%;min-width:100px")
                )
            ),
            div(style="min-width:50px; display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-center-container",
                    style="padding:10px;",
                    icon("arrow-circle-o-right", "right-arrow fa-3x"),
                    tags$br(),
                    icon("arrow-circle-o-left", "left-arrow fa-3x")
                )
            ),
            div(style=
                  "min-width:100px; display:table-cell;",
                div(class="chooser-container chooser-right-container", style="width:100%;",
                    tags$select(class="right", size=size, multiple=multiple, rightChoices,style="width:100%;")
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
}

registerInputHandler("shinyjsexamples.chooser", function(data, ...) {
  if (is.null(data))
    NULL
  else
    list(left=as.character(data$left), right=as.character(data$right))
}, force = TRUE)
```

chooser-bindings.js

```
(function() {

var options = [];
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);
    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      options = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
             $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
      if (selectSingleMatch === true && 
          $(select).children().length === 1) {
        $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
      }
    });
  });
};

function updateChooser(chooser) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var left = chooser.find("select.left");
    var right = chooser.find("select.right");
    var leftArrow = chooser.find(".left-arrow");
    var rightArrow = chooser.find(".right-arrow");

    var canMoveTo = (left.val() || []).length > 0;
    var canMoveFrom = (right.val() || []).length > 0;

    leftArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveFrom);
    rightArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveTo);
}

function move(chooser, source, dest) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var selected = chooser.find(source).children("option:selected");
    var dest = chooser.find(dest);

    // Push back options to left select array
    if(source == '.right'){
      $.each(selected,function(i){
        var sel = selected[i];
        options.push({value: $(sel).val(), text: $(sel).text()});
      });
    }

    dest.children("option:selected").each(function(i, e) {e.selected = false;});
    dest.append(selected);
    updateChooser(chooser);
    chooser.trigger("change");
}

$(".chooser").change(function(){

});

$(document).on("change", ".chooser select", function() {
    updateChooser($(this).parents(".chooser"));
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .right-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .left-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.left", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.right", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

var binding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

binding.find = function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".chooser");
};

binding.initialize = function(el) {
    updateChooser(el);

    /*
      Create separate bindings for each chooser widget
    */
    $('.chooser').each(function(){
      var chooser   = $(this);
      var left_sel  = $(this).find('.left');
      var right_sel = $(this).find('.right');
      var search_b  = $(this).find('.chooser-input-search');

      // Search function
      $(function() {
        $(left_sel).filterByText(search_b, true);
      }); 

      //Enter binding
      // If element in focus
      $('.chooser-input-search').focus(function() {
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
          // If enter pressed
          if(e.which == 13) {

            if( $(search_b).val().length > 2){
              // Save for debuging 
              var sel_options = [];
              $(left_sel).find('option').each(function() {
                var curr_val = $(this).val();
                var curr_txt = $(this).text();

                // Push to debug array
                sel_options.push({value: curr_val, text: curr_txt});

                // Append to tight selection
                $(right_sel).append(
                  $('<option>').text(curr_val).val(curr_txt)
                );

                // Remove option 
                $(this).remove();

              }); // end each
              // Remove options from gloabl options array
              $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];

                $.each(sel_options,function(j){
                  var sel_option = sel_options[j];
                  if (option.value==sel_option.value && option.text==sel_option.text){
                     options.splice(i, 1);
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });  // End enter keybinding
};

binding.getValue = function(el) {
return {
    left: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.left option").map(function(i, e) { return      e.value; })),
    right: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.right option").map(function(i, e) {   return e.value; }))
}
};

binding.setValue = function(el, value) {
// TODO: implement
};

binding.subscribe = function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.chooserBinding", function(e) {
        callback();
    });
};

binding.unsubscribe = function(el) {
    $(el).off(".chooserBinding");
};

binding.getType = function() {
return "shinyjsexamples.chooser";
};

Shiny.inputBindings.register(binding, "shinyjsexamples.chooser");

})();
```

Comment: Thanks Oskar. It works perfectly except for when the user presses enter in the search box without typing anything. When that happens, the entire list is selected. Is it possible instead to not select anyone if the user hasn't written anything and presses enter?

Comment: I updated the answer, now the input needs to be at least 2 characters long alter the `if( $(search_b).val().length > 2)` part to change this. It seems this needs some fine tuning still but it's at least something to work off of.

Comment: Hi Oscar, hope all is going well. When you select a state from the left and push it into the selected bucket, then push it back from the selected bucked to the original list and then search for that state; there are duplicates of the state. Is there an easy way to fix this so that there are never duplicates?